# Is it possible to use a library built with kotlin 1.3.x in a project using kotlin 1.4.x?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I have a project that uses kotlin **1.4.21** and I need to keep this version since I am also using **kotlinx-serialization** which works starting from kotlin **1.4.x** . I also have another library which is built using kotlin **1.3.x** , is there any way to use both libraries in the same project? Currently I am getting build errors indicating that it cannot find the classes from the library using the old kotlin version.

Cannot access 'com.xxx.xxx' which is a supertype of 'com.xx.xxx.xxx'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Comment: That depends on how the library is built (and how it's dependencies are being delivered) but basically it should work now matter what kotlin version was used to build this. Try to make sure that you added dependency properly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The library is distributed through a private artifactory using jfrog. I am sure that I am adding the dependency properly since the error goes away when I switch the project version to use kotlin 1.3.x

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know jFrog but as far as I understand Gradle, during jar packaging, should put everything to the jar and since it's compiled it should not matter whether you are using newer Kotlin or not. I would suggest to attach full error with specific classes and at least the line with dependency from gradle.build - maybe something was deprecated meanwhile and someone will be able to identify and help with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a proguard issue in the mentioned library(using kotlin 1.3.x) which only caused a build error on projects with kotlin 1.4.x . On projects using kotlin 1.3.x it was merely a build warning which did not block running or releasing the project.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `-api-version=1.3` to the Kotlin compiler as a test. This will keep your code compatible with the 1.3 standard library, which you can use to test the integrity of the 1.3 dependency you are trying to import.

If the compiler still fails with the same error, then you will need to build the 1.3 library with 1.4 and deploy it to Artifactory as a new version.

See [Kotlin compatibility modes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/compatibility-modes.html) for more information.